# Display default file but not the extension

Tags: .htaccess, url

I've looked for this all over the place but can't find a specific solution...

Basically, I have something similar to the following:

`www.thename.co/mpany`

I have created a page called `mpany.php` and set that as my default page and I've also added a rule in htaccess so that the `php` file extension doesn't show.

My problem is that when you type in `www.thename.co`, even though it loads `mpany.php` it only displays the base url: `www.thename.co` in the broswer's address bar, whereas I would like it to show: `www.thename.co/mpany`.

Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
DirectoryIndex mpany.php
```

Any pointers?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^$ mpany [R=301,L]` should do the trick. Place it before your existing `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, but that doesn't work because that makes it look for a directory called `mpany`...

Comment: How is that any different from when the user enters `www.thename.co/mpany` directly in the first place? I thought your rule that adds the `.php` extension was supposed to take care of that?

Comment: Sorry mate, maybe I confused you... I want so that when the user enters, `www.thename.co`, it actually takes them to `www.thename.co\mpany` but also display exactly that in the address bar.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you want. Does the rule I suggested not accomplish that? Then please describe what happens instead.

Comment: What happens instead is that when I type in `www.thename.co` it looks for a directory called `mpany` and returns an error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex mpany.php
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /mpany/ [L,R]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey @anubhava, should this line `RewriteRule ^$ /mpany/ [L,R]` have that second forward slash?

Comment: Actually, to answer my own question, when I remove the second slash, it gives me the desired result! Man, thanks SO much!